# Deleting and moving all negative numbers from one list to another list - Did not work?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to move the negative numbers from one array to another. The result I have misses certain elements, e.g. -12 and -14.

```
    arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
    arr1=[]
    for i in arr:
            if i < 0:
                arr1.append(i)
                arr.remove(i)
    print (arr,arr1)
```

The result is:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -12, -14] [-11, -13, -15]

Why -12 and -14 are not moved?

Comment: Try to use List Comprehension - it's best than *change the list items during looping*...```arr1 = [x for x in arr if x < 0]```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you did not get your items removed is just because while looping and removing at the same time, the *pointer* index is just jumping off...

It's best to do 2-loops, or you insist one loop then - doing from the backwards. It's because operation from the backward, the operation will NOT affect the indexing.

```py
for x in arr[::-1]:
    if x < 0: 
        arr1.append(x)
        arr.remove(x)

    
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> arr1                        # if orig. order is not important 
[-15, -14, -13, -12, -11]
```

#### To understand what's happening in your original code: Run this::

```py
for idx, x in enumerate(arr):
    if x < 0:
        print(idx, x)
        arr1.append(x)
        arr.remove(x)
        
print (arr,arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element in arr while looping, this change its content for the next round.
correct code is the following in two steps:

```
arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
arr1=[]
for i in arr:
        print (i)
        if i < 0:
            arr1.append(i)
for i in arr1:
    arr.remove(i)
print (arr,arr1)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] [-11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
```

HTH